# Click on Clip Art icon on Vector asset import wizard doesn't working

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

Clicking on Clip Art Button on Vector Asset Import Wizard causes an android studio JSON de-serializing exception of material icons metadata file and nothing happening

**Exception**

```
Error obtaining metadata file

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: "ٹل›ذ"
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:944)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:870)
    at com.android.tools.idea.material.icons.metadata.MaterialIconsMetadata$Companion.parse(MaterialIconsMetadata.kt:47)
    at com.android.tools.idea.material.icons.utils.MaterialIconsUtils.getMetadata(MaterialIconsUtils.kt:92)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.assetstudio.MaterialVdIconsProvider$Companion.loadMaterialVdIcons(MaterialVdIconsProvider.kt:89)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.assetstudio.MaterialVdIconsProvider.loadMaterialVdIcons(MaterialVdIconsProvider.kt)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.assetstudio.ui.IconPickerDialog.<init>(IconPickerDialog.java:237)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.assetstudio.ui.IconPickerDialog.<init>(IconPickerDialog.java:155)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.assetstudio.ui.VectorIconButton.lambda$new$0(VectorIconButton.java:61)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)

/*other code*/
```

I can't import Vector Asset to my project what can I do to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vector Asset Import Wizard` did not worked for me a few times after some upgrades or unknown reasons.

Clip Art was showing any icon, although `sdk` path had `icons` folder.

Please, try these steps below. Let me know, if it does not work for you. Hope it helps.

Steps to recreate vector `icons` folder

- Go to your Android `sdk` directory
- Remove or rename `icons` folder
- Try to create a new Vector Asset.

Android Studio will create a new `icons` folder.